# Looking for a good version of Maimonides Introduction to his Commentary on the Mishna available online

Tags: books-generally, internet, product-recommendation, rambam

I while ago, I read through most of an English translation Rambam's Introduction to his Commentary on the Mishnah. I think it was an earlier edition of [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1880582287), but I'm not sure.

I'm looking for a good online version of the hebrew (either in download format or straight text).

I found [this](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/hakdama/tohen-m-2.htm), but I don't know anything about its accuracy.

Some of the things I would prefer include:

- Lots of references and sources
- Clear and easy to read
- If I have a choice, I would prefer something I can download (e.g. pdf).

I guess I'm looking for something close what is printed in the [Hakdamot volume of the Rambam Leam](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?main_page=product_sefer_info&cPath=16&products_id=129&zenid=mk13v8pnbt5782prooq79flvs4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14284&st=&pgnum=9

Answer (score 3):

[The Wagshal Mishnayot available on Hebrewbooks.org](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37939&st=&pgnum=44) has another decent one, very similar to one @Shmuel answered [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9521/603). It appears to be the same edition, just re-typeset, with newer, cleaner letters.