# Where can I find an English version of Rambam's Introduction to Mishnah?

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, internet, mishna, english

I am looking for an online copy of an English translation to Rambam's introduction to the whole Mishna.

I have found a few copies in Hebrew, but I am looking for something legible and understandable in English.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for asking this question. Consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site. For more information about the site see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9520/looking-for-a-good-version-of-maimonides-introduction-to-his-commentary-on-the-m?s=0%7C1.7655

Comment: haven't used it but this is the book you're looking for http://www.amazon.com/Maimonides-Introduction-Talmud-Translation-Commentary/dp/1880582287

Answer (score 1):

Try Aronson's ["Maimonides' Introduction to His Commentary on the Mishnah"](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=L6_XAAAAMAAJ&q=rambam%20mishnah&dq=rambam%20mishnah&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIidGctL6LxwIVwjsUCh3oMwMe) (1995).

Comment: This is not an online copy.